# SharePoint 2010 taxonomy import and export to csv

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, import, managed-metadata-service

Currently I am working with taxonomies and multi language packs.  So I want to import a csv with all terms in a term store in different languages.  However I cannot find an example of how the csv should be in order to take all language differences.

I also tried to export a test term store which has terms in two languages but it is only giving me the default language terms.

Any suggestions on how to export and import all terms in all languages or how to formulate my csv in order for the import to read all terms in multi languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this tool from Codeplex, and entered in the import CSV the column LCID with german language (LCID=1031). Worked smooth when transferring from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2012

As a hint for german speaking areas, please keep in mind to use Unicode settings and the comma instead the semicolon as list separator, then this works smooth as silked

http://termsetimporter.codeplex.com/